# Create 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have problem creating 2d array in javascript. Here is my code:

```
var arr = new Array([]);
arr[0][0] = "1st data from array";
arr[1][0] = "2nd data from array";
document.write(arr[0][1] + " " + arr[1][0]);
```

What I should do to make it work?

Comment: I’d suggest using array literal syntax instead of constructor syntax, i.e. `var arr=[['1st …'],['2nd …']]` instead of the top three lines. Also, don’t use `document.write`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will throw an error because arr[0] and arr[1] are not set to be arrays yet. Try:

```
var arr = [[],[]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize an item in `arr` before setting `arr[i][x]`:

```
var arr = new Array([]);
arr[0] = arr[1] = [];
arr[0][1] = "1st data from array";
arr[1][0] = "2nd data from array";
document.write(arr[0][1] + " " + arr[1][0]);
```